# Is it possible to run Azure SDK on Linux?

Tags: linux, azure, sdk

Is it possible to run Azure SDK on Linux?

I want to develop a Java app that I want to deploy on Windows Azure, but I'm using Linux Ubuntu now.

Any idea for this problem?

Comment: You need Windows if you develop for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Windows Azure command line tool for Mac and Linux, [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/). This will let you create / deploy / manage your VMs, network endpoints, data disks, cloud services (web/worker roles), certificates, Websites, and maybe a few other things I'm forgetting.

You should have no issue running Java apps in an Ubuntu Virtual Machine, and Ubuntu is one of the OS images available in the Virtual Machine gallery.

Comment: actually i want to develop java application on eclipse like on : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944%28VS.103%29.aspx but i'm using ubuntu.i found http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/ to download java azure sdk for linux.But i don;t know how i can work with it.any reference for install azue java sdk on ubuntu ? so that i can develop java app using eclipse in ubuntu.

Comment: Just like you would with any other SDK.  This is not an emulator, you need windows for that.  It simply gives you methods and functions for calling azure services.

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java

Comment: I stand corrected. It looks like they do have emulation tools!

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your Java application and deploy it on Windows Azure from your Linux machine following the steps described [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/).

If you need to operate infrastructure, you can download the Azure command-line tool. You can also use the VM Feature (Technical Preview) and run your Ubuntu Server on Azure if you feel more comfortable with that.

Either way, operating from infrastructure or from platform, you can deploy your scenario on Azure. Even specific bits could run as worker roles. I would encourage you to check the Java Dev Center for Azure I mentioned.